# Google map Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, undefined, google-geocoder

I Using the google `geocoder` to get the `lat` and `lng`, when `initMap` had been called, I got two alert, first value is `undefined` ,and second get the `lat` value, what is the problem to get the `undefined` value, and how to resolve this? I need to get the value immediately.

```
function initMap(){
      var addr = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA';
      var code = getLatLng(addr);
      alert(code.lat); // --> alert_1
}

function getLatLng(addr) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({'address': addr }, function (results, status) {
       var lat,lng = 0;
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
         }
         alert(lat); // --> alert_2
         return {lat : lat,lng : lng};
     });
 }
```

Comment: `lat()` to `lat` & `lng()` to `lng` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `geocode` is an asynchronous function. Therefore, you get `undefined` for `code.lat` in the alert of the `initMap` function and the geocoded value in the `getLatLng` function. You can add a callback function to the parameters of the `getLatLng` function to solve your problem like this:

```js
function initMap() {
  var addr = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA';
  getLatLng(addr, function(code) {
    alert(code.lat);
  });
}

function getLatLng(addr, cb) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({'address': addr }, function (results, status) {
    var lat,lng = 0;
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      }
      cb({lat: lat, lng: lng});
  });
}
```

Comment: oh... It still callback a undefined value.

Comment: It callback a undefined value that cause a error at `alert(code.lat);` can not get the` lat`

Comment: I updated my answer so that the callback function should now work properly